# How to close a Dialog in Android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

How do I close a Dialog in android programmatically for example by a button?

Imagine I have a Dialog with a OK button on it, and want to close it by OK button, but I cant do that!

I googled and found nothing useful, and almost all of them for closing AlertDialog not a Dialog.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can call [`dismiss`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29) on the dialog.

Comment: thank you :) thats worked! sorry about my silly Q :) thanks all :)

Comment: I used .setPositiveButton("ok ", new
                                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                        dismissDialog(DIALOG_Success);
                                    }
                                })  but when I show diaolog again,dialog shows old message.I wrote   Activity.this.showDialog(DIALOG_Success,arg); can you help me?

Answer (score 15):

This is an example of how to create a AlertDialog with 2 Buttons (OK and cancel).
When clicking the cancel button,

> dialog.dismiss()

is called to close the dialog.

From anywhere outside, you could call

> builder.dismiss();

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("Some message.")
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           // do something
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                   });

            builder.show();
```

Comment: there is no such method like builder.dismiss();

Comment: You need to call the `.create()` method on `builder` to have access to `dismiss()`. 
First do `setNegativeButton(...).create();`, then `builder.dismiss();`

Answer (score 9):

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Only this line will close it. :-)

Implement it in the onClickListener.

Comment: it's need just dismiss() method from inside of dialog class! thank you Helmisek :)

Comment: Sure just call `dismiss()` method of DialogFragment

Answer (score 7):

You can use the methods [`cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel%28%29) or [`dismiss()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29). The method `cancel()` essentially the same as calling dismiss(), but it will also call your [`DialogInterface.OnCancelListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html) (if registered).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the `dismiss();` option, if you have your dialog as a separate `Activity` (s.a. `DialogActivity`), another way to close it is to call:

```
   finish();
```

Call this method inside the `OnClickListener` class' `onClick()` method.

This will call the `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` methods consequently and kill the current activity - same as **Back** button.